# insert html content in mail using intent

Tags: android

I need to send mail with html content.Html content is coming from back end .I have tried using Html.fromHtml and passed it to Intent.EXTRA_TEXT but I am not getting the desired result my html content contains images and hyperlink but after using Html.fromHtml i am getting text only

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    String[] recipients = {"wantedEmail@gmail.com"};
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, recipients);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "emailTitle:");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,Html.fromHtml(emailContent));
    intent.setType("text/html");

    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC, "ghi");
    intent.setType("message/rfc822");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send mail"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, emailContent);
```

Putting that you should be able to get what you see

Comment: directly passing emailcontent simply put the html code not the rendered content on my gmail composer